# mysql row update many times in single transaction

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to update a table row (single row) many times in a single mysql  transaction ?
I got a lock time out error when trying to do this
is there a solution for this please ?

Comment: Post your code that produces time-outs.

Comment: Locks only apply between different transactions, a transaction can't lock itself out. There's nothing wrong with updating the same row multiple times, although there are usually ways to change your query to avoid it.